# asp.net controls in asp.net MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-2, asp.net-controls

I have installed Visual Studio 2010 express edition which has MVC in it. I am creating my first application and I noticed that I can include basic asp.net controls like [label, gridview, datagrid, drop downbox] in it. and all event related to these controls displayed on the view.

My question is:

Is it good to use asp.net controls in MVC or should I practice more on HTML part and JQuery? Would it harm page speed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think it's a good idea.

MVC embodies the idea of giving you full control at the client-side and at the server-side. While ASP.NET server side controls were there to mimic the desktop-based development which most developers were used to. They are easy to use but are less flexible and some issues (like ViewState) could really hard to solve.

IMO I think you should only go for ASP.NET controls if you are bounded by some legacy code

Comment: Thanks for your inputs. I think I should seek alternate of asp.net controls which like HTML... css and JQuery. Am I correct ?

Comment: There are asp.net mvc controls as well. yea mostly. though you can also get asp.net mvc controls e.g. check out telerik's website. they have separate controls for mvc and old asp.net controls